# LinkedIn Auto Post using Django

Tags: python, django

Wordpress has a plugin called 'LinkedIn Auto Publish' where everyting you post a blot, the blog automatically gets posted in the linkedin as well. Is there something similar in Django?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Django is not a cms or blog engine.

Comment: If you want you can create the package and open source it please...

Comment: @DanielRoseman But you can make a Blog Applcication with Django